# Web Services Not connecting in First Attempt

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I am developing Application for Windows Phone using .Net Compact Framework 3.5

I am trying to connect Web Services from this application.

It is not connecting it in First Attempt, but it is  connecting successfully in second and further attempts.

In First Attempt, It is giving "Web Exception" Error.
[image]

I am using following code for connecting:

```
SalesService.SalesService obj = new SalesService.SalesService(); 
 string s = obj.CheckForValidService();
```

It is giving error in CheckForValidService method from Reference.cs file.

[image: Error Details]

Comment: Is there a message text on the Web Exception? It could be timing out due to the service taking to long to respond. If it's the first call to the service, it can take a while. You can attempt to change the timeout, or if the service is yours, then debug the service to make sure it returns before the device times out.

Comment: are you using wlan or wwan connection? If wwan, it may take a while for the connection being established.

Comment: I am using Wi-fi LAN for connecting with device. But I am receiving same error when connecting with emulator.

Comment: You *must* provide use with the contents of the "Web Exception" if you want further help.  It will contain a wealth of information, and most likely the key to solving your problem.

Comment: @tcarvin, I have attached screenshot of Web Exception.

Comment: @FredrikLjung, Don't change meaning of question when suggesting.

Comment: So the next question is, did you do the two actions listed in your screen shot?  "Check the Response property of the exception..." and "Check the Status property of the exception...".  Please collect that information and post it back for us all.

Comment: @tcarvin , Please check screenshot of Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the old Expect-100 header issue.  You will need to surpress the use of that header.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

MSDN details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue(v=vs.90).aspx

Stackoverflow details:

[The request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation Failed - Using Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198393/the-request-failed-with-http-status-417-expectation-failed-using-web-services)