# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (417)

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, service, windows-services

I hosted my WCF Service Library using a Windows Service on our server. My client application is a Winforms application. The App.Config of this Winforms app is as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Rahat.Properties.Settings.RahatConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.50.9;Initial Catalog=Rahat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=******"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerDateTime" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.50.9:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RahatWcfServiceLibrary/ServerDateTime/mex"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServerDateTime"
                      contract="DateTimeService.IServerDateTime" 
                      name="BasicHttpBinding_IServerDateTime" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When the client app calls the WCF Service method then gets the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an
>   unexpected response: (417) Expectation failed. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (417)
>   Expectation failed.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check if this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198393/the-request-failed-with-http-status-417-expectation-failed-using-web-services

Comment: @joreldraw, I read the link, but the issue was not solved.